# addHitRegion any working example?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Can't find or create any working example with click detection with addHitRegion on canvas.

Comment: https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/canvas/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion#Return_Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this feature isn't implemented yet. However i've found useful link to do the same thing.

http://shifteleven.com/articles/2012/01/08/mouse-clicks-for-html5-cavas-entities-via-paths